# spring boot mfa totp code verification on login not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, totp

I am trying to implement mfa authentication in my app using totp. Bellow is the library i use. All is going well for registering the user, i receive the qr code, scan it and get every 30 secs the code in google authenticator. When i am trying to login to verify the code, the code verification doesnt work (in auth service, method Verify). I've spent several hours but cant figure it out, tried different users, logs but without success.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>dev.samstevens.totp</groupId>
            <artifactId>totp</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

this is my code

AuthContoller.java

```
import com.example.jsonfaker.model.dto.LoginRequest;
import com.example.jsonfaker.model.dto.SignupRequest;
import com.example.jsonfaker.model.dto.VerifyRequest;
import com.example.jsonfaker.service.Exporter;
import com.example.jsonfaker.service.UserAuthService;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
@CrossOrigin
public class AuthController {
    private final Exporter exporter;

    private final UserAuthService userAuthService;

    public AuthController(Exporter exporter, UserAuthService userAuthService) {
        this.exporter = exporter;
        this.userAuthService = userAuthService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        String response = userAuthService.login(loginRequest);
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .body(response);
    }

    @PostMapping("/register2FA")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> registerUser2FA(@Valid @RequestBody SignupRequest signupRequest) throws Exception {

        userAuthService.register2FA(signupRequest);
        byte[] qrCodeBytes = userAuthService.mfaAccountSetup(signupRequest.getUsername());

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline;filename=\""+exporter.exportFileNameQR() + ".png\"")
                .body(qrCodeBytes);
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignupRequest signupRequest) throws Exception {
        userAuthService.simpleRegister(signupRequest);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PostMapping("/verify")
    public ResponseEntity<String> authenticateUser2FA(@Valid @RequestBody VerifyRequest verifyRequest) throws Exception {
        String response = userAuthService.verify(verifyRequest.getUsername(), verifyRequest.getCode());
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .body(response);
    }


}
```

this is my token manager

```
import dev.samstevens.totp.code.*;
import dev.samstevens.totp.exceptions.QrGenerationException;
import dev.samstevens.totp.qr.QrData;
import dev.samstevens.totp.qr.QrGenerator;
import dev.samstevens.totp.secret.SecretGenerator;
import dev.samstevens.totp.time.SystemTimeProvider;
import dev.samstevens.totp.time.TimeProvider;
import dev.samstevens.totp.util.Utils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("mfaTokenManager")
public class DefaultMFATokenManager implements MFATokenManager {


    private final SecretGenerator secretGenerator;


    private final QrGenerator qrGenerator;


    private final CodeVerifier codeVerifier;

    public DefaultMFATokenManager(SecretGenerator secretGenerator, QrGenerator qrGenerator, CodeVerifier codeVerifier) {
        this.secretGenerator = secretGenerator;
        this.qrGenerator = qrGenerator;
        this.codeVerifier = codeVerifier;
    }

    @Override
    public String generateSecretKey() {
        return secretGenerator.generate();
    }

    @Override
    public String getQRCode(String secret) throws QrGenerationException {
        QrData data = new QrData.Builder().label("MFA")
                .secret(secret)
                .issuer("Daniel token")
                .algorithm(HashingAlgorithm.SHA1)
                .digits(6)
                .period(30)
                .build();
        return Utils.getDataUriForImage(
                qrGenerator.generate(data),
                qrGenerator.getImageMimeType()
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean verifyTotp(String code, String secret) {
        TimeProvider timeProvider = new SystemTimeProvider();
        CodeGenerator codeGenerator = new DefaultCodeGenerator();
        CodeVerifier verifier = new DefaultCodeVerifier(codeGenerator, timeProvider);
        System.out.println(timeProvider.getTime());
        System.out.println(codeGenerator);

        return verifier.isValidCode(secret, code);
    }
}
```

this is my auth service

```
import com.example.jsonfaker.model.Roles;
import com.example.jsonfaker.model.SystemUser;
import com.example.jsonfaker.model.dto.LoginRequest;
import com.example.jsonfaker.model.dto.SignupRequest;
import com.example.jsonfaker.model.dto.TokenResponse;
import com.example.jsonfaker.repository.RolesRepository;
import com.example.jsonfaker.repository.SystemUserRepository;
import com.example.jsonfaker.security.AuthoritiesConstants;
import com.example.jsonfaker.security.jwt.JwtUtils;
import com.example.jsonfaker.twoFA.MFATokenManager;
import com.example.jsonfaker.twoFA.MfaTokenData;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static java.util.Objects.nonNull;

@Service
public class UserAuthService {
    private final SystemUserRepository systemUserRepository;
    private final RolesRepository rolesRepository;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    private final MFATokenManager mfaTokenManager;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final LoginUserService loginUserService;
    private final JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    public UserAuthService(SystemUserRepository systemUserRepository, RolesRepository rolesRepository, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder, MFATokenManager mfaTokenManager, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, LoginUserService loginUserService, JwtUtils jwtUtils) {
        this.systemUserRepository = systemUserRepository;
        this.rolesRepository = rolesRepository;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        this.mfaTokenManager = mfaTokenManager;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.loginUserService = loginUserService;
        this.jwtUtils = jwtUtils;
    }

    public void simpleRegister(SignupRequest signupRequest) throws Exception {
        if(systemUserRepository.findByUsername(signupRequest.getUsername()).isPresent()){
            throw new Exception("User with this username exists");
        }

        Roles simpleUserRole = new Roles();
        simpleUserRole.setName(AuthoritiesConstants.USER);

        SystemUser user = new SystemUser();
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(signupRequest.getPassword()));
        user.setUsername(signupRequest.getUsername());
        user.setAuthorities(rolesRepository.findAllByName("ROLE_USER").stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        user.setSecret(mfaTokenManager.generateSecretKey());
        systemUserRepository.save(user);

    }

    public void register2FA(SignupRequest signupRequest) throws Exception {
        if(systemUserRepository.findByUsername(signupRequest.getUsername()).isPresent()){
            throw new Exception("User with this username exists");
        }
        Roles simpleUserRole = new Roles();
        simpleUserRole.setName(AuthoritiesConstants.USER);

        SystemUser user = new SystemUser();
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(signupRequest.getPassword()));
        user.setUsername(signupRequest.getUsername());
        user.setAuthorities(rolesRepository.findAllByName("ROLE_USER").stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        user.setTwoFAisEnabled(Boolean.TRUE);
        user.setSecret(mfaTokenManager.generateSecretKey());
        systemUserRepository.save(user);
    }

    public byte[] mfaAccountSetup(String username) throws Exception {
        SystemUser user = systemUserRepository.findByUsername(username).get();
        if (!nonNull(user)){
            throw new Exception("Unable to find user with this username");
        }
        if(!user.isTwoFAisEnabled()){
            throw new Exception("2FA is not enabled for this account");
        }
        MfaTokenData token =  new MfaTokenData(mfaTokenManager.getQRCode(user.getSecret()), user.getSecret());
        System.out.println("Mfa code :" +token.getMfaCode());

        String base64Image = token.getQrCode().split(",")[1];
        byte[] imageBytes = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Image);
        return imageBytes;
    }

    public String login(LoginRequest loginRequest){
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginRequest.getUsername(),
                        loginRequest.getPassword()
                )
        );
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        if(systemUserRepository.findByUsername(loginRequest.getUsername()).get().isTwoFAisEnabled()){
            return "verify code now";
        }

        SystemUser userDetails = (SystemUser) authentication.getPrincipal();

        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(userDetails);

        return new TokenResponse(jwt).toString();

    }

    public String verify(String username, String code) throws Exception {

        SystemUser user = systemUserRepository.findByUsername(username).get();
        if (!nonNull(user)){
            throw new Exception("Unable to find user with this username");
        }

        if (!mfaTokenManager.verifyTotp(code, user.getSecret())){
            return "unable to auth";
        }
        return "token here";

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also paste if you are facing any errors ? if so, which ones? Have you tried debugging ? at what statement does it go wrong sort of ? Also consider adding few log statements for your own reference

Comment: im getting in request response "unable to auth", but in app console there is no error, i would like to try to debug verifyTotp from token manager, but the implementation is in a decompiled class file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found the problem, on my phone the time was delayed by 2 minutes, I've set it to be the same as on my computer and worked. The problem is that when validating the token the app uses an interval of 30 seconds for each token generation, and if the delay on the phone or other device is bigger than 30 sec in future or past the timestamp doesnt match the one used for verification.

Here is the documentation for the library i used, make sure to read it carefully before using it.
https://github.com/samdjstevens/java-totp

Here is the article which i followed in my project:
https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-security/two-factor-authentication-with-spring-security/

Useful reading before starting a project using TOTP:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-time-based-one-time-passwords-work-and-why-you-should-use-them-in-your-app-fdd2b9ed43c3/

A youtube video about 2FA:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXFYT-BG2So

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this thread while trying to learn TOTP concepts and after 2/3 hours of working through the issues I think I have the solution going.

1. POM dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>dev.samstevens.totp</groupId>
    <artifactId>totp-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

2. TOTPConstants.java

```
package com.spsllc.config;

import dev.samstevens.totp.code.HashingAlgorithm;

public interface TOTPConstants {

    int DIGITS = 6;
    int SECRET_CHARACTER_LENGTH = 32;
    int CODE_VALIDITY_IN_SECONDS = 30;
    int TIME_PERIOD_DISCREPANCY = 1;
    HashingAlgorithm HASHING_ALGO = HashingAlgorithm.SHA1;
}
```

3. TOTPConfig.java

```
package com.spsllc.config;

import static com.spsllc.config.TOTPConstants.CODE_VALIDITY_IN_SECONDS;
import static com.spsllc.config.TOTPConstants.DIGITS;
import static com.spsllc.config.TOTPConstants.HASHING_ALGO;
import static com.spsllc.config.TOTPConstants.SECRET_CHARACTER_LENGTH;
import static com.spsllc.config.TOTPConstants.TIME_PERIOD_DISCREPANCY;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import dev.samstevens.totp.code.CodeGenerator;
import dev.samstevens.totp.code.CodeVerifier;
import dev.samstevens.totp.code.DefaultCodeGenerator;
import dev.samstevens.totp.code.DefaultCodeVerifier;
import dev.samstevens.totp.qr.QrGenerator;
import dev.samstevens.totp.qr.ZxingPngQrGenerator;
import dev.samstevens.totp.secret.DefaultSecretGenerator;
import dev.samstevens.totp.secret.SecretGenerator;
import dev.samstevens.totp.time.NtpTimeProvider;
import dev.samstevens.totp.time.TimeProvider;

@Configuration
public class TOTPConfig {

    @Bean
    public TimeProvider timeProvider() throws Exception {
        return new NtpTimeProvider("pool.ntp.org");
    }

    @Bean
    public SecretGenerator secretGenerator() {
        return new DefaultSecretGenerator(SECRET_CHARACTER_LENGTH);
    }

    @Bean
    public QrGenerator qrGenerator() {
        return new ZxingPngQrGenerator();
    }

    @Bean
    public CodeGenerator codeGenerator() {
        return new DefaultCodeGenerator(HASHING_ALGO, DIGITS);
    }

    @Bean
    public CodeVerifier codeVerifier() throws Exception {
        DefaultCodeVerifier verifier = new DefaultCodeVerifier(codeGenerator(), timeProvider());
        verifier.setTimePeriod(CODE_VALIDITY_IN_SECONDS);
        verifier.setAllowedTimePeriodDiscrepancy(TIME_PERIOD_DISCREPANCY);
        return verifier;
    }
}
```

4. TOTPController.java

```
package com.spsllc.controller;

import static com.spsllc.config.TOTPConstants.CODE_VALIDITY_IN_SECONDS;
import static com.spsllc.config.TOTPConstants.DIGITS;
import static com.spsllc.config.TOTPConstants.HASHING_ALGO;
import static dev.samstevens.totp.util.Utils.getDataUriForImage;

import java.time.Instant;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

import dev.samstevens.totp.code.CodeGenerator;
import dev.samstevens.totp.code.CodeVerifier;
import dev.samstevens.totp.exceptions.QrGenerationException;
import dev.samstevens.totp.qr.QrData;
import dev.samstevens.totp.qr.QrGenerator;
import dev.samstevens.totp.secret.SecretGenerator;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Controller
@Slf4j
public class TOTPController {

    @Autowired
    private SecretGenerator secretGenerator;

    @Autowired
    private CodeGenerator codeGenerator;

    @Autowired
    private QrGenerator qrGenerator;

    @Autowired
    private CodeVerifier verifier;

    @GetMapping("/totp/setup")
    public ModelAndView setupDevice(ModelAndView modelAndView) throws QrGenerationException {
        // Use this to generate unique secret per user/device and store it against the user profile in DB
        // String secret = secretGenerator.generate();
        // Use this to generate unique secret per user/device and store it against the user profile in DB
        String secret = "XFRUQ2SSFFXLYGOS7RDIGFQ7RHQUFJC3";
        QrData data = new QrData.Builder()
                .label("john.doe@example.com")
                .secret(secret)
                .issuer("Imaginary Inc.,")
                .digits(DIGITS)
                .period(CODE_VALIDITY_IN_SECONDS)
                .algorithm(HASHING_ALGO)
                .build();

        String qrCodeImage = getDataUriForImage(
                qrGenerator.generate(data),
                qrGenerator.getImageMimeType());

        modelAndView.setViewName("content/totp-setup.html");
        modelAndView.addObject("qrCodeImageData", qrCodeImage);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping(value= "/totp/verify/{totpCode}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<TOTPCode> verify(@PathVariable(name = "totpCode") String code) {
        TOTPCode totpCode = new TOTPCode();
        totpCode.setCode(code);
        totpCode.setVerificationStatus("INCORRECT CODE");
        if (verifier.isValidCode("XFRUQ2SSFFXLYGOS7RDIGFQ7RHQUFJC3", code)) {
            totpCode.setVerificationStatus("CORRECT CODE");
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<TOTPCode>(totpCode, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/totp/code", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<TOTPCode> generateCode() throws Exception {
        TOTPCode totpCode = new TOTPCode();
        totpCode.setCode(codeGenerator.generate("XFRUQ2SSFFXLYGOS7RDIGFQ7RHQUFJC3", Instant.now().getEpochSecond() / CODE_VALIDITY_IN_SECONDS));
        return new ResponseEntity<TOTPCode>(totpCode, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public static class TOTPCode {
        String code;
        String verificationStatus;
    }
}
```

5. src\main\resources\templates\content\totp-setup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
    <link th:rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/popper.js/2.9.3/umd/popper.min.js}"></script>

    <link th:rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" th:href="@{/apple-touch-icon.png}" />
    <link th:rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" th:href="@{/favicon-32x32.png}" />
    <link th:rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" th:href="@{/favicon-16x16.png}" />
    <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
    <link th:rel="manifest" th:href="@{/site.webmanifest}" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-2">
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
            <h3>Scan this QR code in your authenticator app...</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img th:src="${qrCodeImageData}" style="height: 100px; width:100px;" class="rounded float-start" alt="TOTP QR Code"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

6. Screenshots:
   [image: Setup/onboard the user using QR Code]
   [image: get the code]
   [image: verify the code]
7. Additional thoughts

I have tested this against following authenticator apps. I have also tested the solution with 8-digit-code with a validity of 60 seconds. It worked fine.

I could not get it to work with SHA256/SHA512 hashing algorithms (only Google authenticator worked, but not Secureauth Authenticate). So for now, I am sticking with SHA1.

```
a) Microsoft authenticator
b) Google authenticator
c) SecureAuth Authenticator
d) Symantec VIP Access app
e) 2FA Authy
f) Authy
```